# Problems loading language model in DMP format in CMU Sphinx

Tags: speech-recognition, voice-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I tried compiling CMU Sphinx from source and tried to recognize voice commands using mic . My command looks like this:

```
 pocketsphinx_continuous.exe -inmic yes -hmm model/en-us/en-us -lm model/en-us/en-us.lm.bin -dict model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict**
```

I get an error saying that en-us.lm.bin is not a dump file. What am I supposed to do now?

```
 ERROR: "ngram_model_dmp.c", line 121: Wrong magic header size number 54726965: model/en-us/en-us.lm.bin is not a dump file**
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update sphinxbase and pocketsphinx to use latest models.

Comment: you need to pull latest version from github